# Preventing others from calling a function based on a condition, but always allowing the class to call it?

Tags: c++, refactoring

I wasn't sure how to call this. Basically I have a Label widget. It has an auto size feature. The problem is I do not know who calls setSize(); I need to know if the class called it or if the user of the label called it because you cannot resize an auto sizing widget. I cannot directly change the size because, well 1, it's not very OO, and 2 I cannot access it because the size is in the base class. I can only override setSize() but without knowing who called it, I cannot filter out anyone.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the implementation into a (renamed) private method, make `setSize()` into a wrapper that checks the condition.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need a private/protected override.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a private `setSizeInternal` method, and a public `setSize` method that checks the condition.

Answer (score 0):

as other have said, you need to make a private/protected setSize which can set the the size without condition checking and a public one that performs the condition checking. You would have the public one call the private only if the conditions are met